# Wix: Edit Control not setting property

Tags: wix

I have an issue with Wix where an Edit control is not setting a property. I am using the property in a XmlFile node to modify an .xml file copied to the install location. The value of the property IS being correctly set in the file (the default value is being used) but I cannot seem to set the property with a value from the Edit control. This is driving me nuts.

```
<Fragment>
    <Property Id="CUSTOMERNAMEPROPERTY" Value="Some default value" Secure="yes" />

    <UI>
        <Control Id="CustomerNameEdit" Type="Edit" X="120" Y="75" Width="220" Height="18" Property="CUSTOMERNAMEPROPERTY" Text="{80}" Indirect="yes" />
    </UI>
</Fragment>
```

What is wrong with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Indirect attribute should be set to "no". Edit controls should reference their properties directly.

Also, make sure that you use a [public property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (only uppercase letters in its name). Private properties use their default values during install.

Comment: I swore i tried that earlier and it didn't work...but now it does, so I will mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for having the property name all UPPERCASE.  I had the same problem and UPPERCASING fixed it!!!!  I'd give you + 1 million if I could

Comment: OMG, love u and your answer man. they were 2 hard days looking for a solution of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare your property inside `<UI>` element:

```
<Fragment>
    <UI>
        <Property Id="CUSTOMERNAMEPROPERTY" Value="Some default value" Secure="yes" />
        <Control Id="CustomerNameEdit" Type="Edit" X="120" Y="75" Width="220" Height="18" Property="CUSTOMERNAMEPROPERTY" Text="{80}" Indirect="yes" />
    </UI>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: This is actually not true; UPPERCASE properties are registered in a property table in the MSI wherever they are in the wsx files.